# How to stop lines of code from automatically shifting to the next line whenever I resize the window of the editor?

Tags: html, formatting, sublimetext2, text-editor, sublimetext

I am using Sublime Text 2. When I am on an HTML file. If I resize the window. The code at the very end shifts down to the next line. How do I stop this from happening? I want the code to continue onward, so I will have to scroll side to side to see the rest of the code and not have the shift to the next line.

I have taken screenshots to better illustrate what I am referring to.

[image: Full window of code]

After window has been resized. Notice the number lines? How do I stop that? I'd rather scroll right to see the rest of the code instead of having the code jump to the next line.

[image: Resized window]

I noticed this only happens in an HTML file.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Look in the **default** Preferences.sublime-settings file for the setting below:

```
// Disables horizontal scrolling if enabled.
// May be set to true, false, or "auto", where it will be disabled for
// source code, and otherwise enabled.
"word_wrap": "auto",
```

---

If you want the default for word wrap to be *off* for *all* syntax types:

Copy `"word_wrap": "auto",` into your **user** `Preferences.sublime-settings` file

If you want the default for word wrap to be *off* for code and *off* for HTML but *on* for other syntax types:

Copy `"word_wrap": "auto",` into the `HTML.sublime-settings` file

---

Set it to `"word_wrap": "false",`.

Now your default for HTML will be word wrap is *off*.

You can change this anytime by toggling the `Word Wrap` item in the `View` menu *or* by launching the Control Panel and typing enough of `word wrap` until the `Word Wrap: Toggle` item is selected and hitting `Return`.

Comment: +1. Just to clarify, putting this code in that settings file will disable word wrap for _any_ syntax, not just HTML files. If you want that behavior, or any other option for that matter, to only apply to files with a certain syntax type, open such a file and edit your syntax-specific preferences from the menu and put the above code there.

Answer (score 23):

Just uncheck "Word wrap" in the "view" menu.

Answer (score 17):

1. Open an HTML file with Sublime Text.
2. Choose Sublime Text > Preferences > Settings - Syntax Specific.
3. A file named `HTML.sublime-settings` will open.
4. Insert the following:

   ```json
   {
       "word_wrap": "false"
   }
   ```
5. Save the file.

Comment: I think it only needs:
"word_wrap": "false"

Answer (score 1):

You can [specify a particular number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25901060/241211) to display before wrapping, irrespective of the window width. Put your desired number of columns in the relevant preferences file:

```json
"wrap_width": 80,
```

This is probably not what you want with HTML, but it helps with readability for things like Markdown, TeX, or plain text when the author didn't use line breaks.